# Public Computers randomly dropping internet connection

Tags: networking, wired

I just started working at a Public Library in East Tennessee we are having persistent problems with our public computers losing internet connectivity repeatedly out of the blue. The problem most typically manifests when a customer is browsing any web page they simply become unable to load any new pages. If I open a command line I can ping google (17 or 16ms) no problem but loading any new webpage doesn't work. The only thing we have gotten to work is to simply restart the machines. 99% of the time they'll work again on the first try. But sometimes they'll only work for half an hour before the problem comes back.

release/renewing the IP addresses does not resolve the issue.

All the computers (except the staff machines which have had no issues) are set to recieve their IP addresses automatically (staff machines have defined IP addresses). So I don't think it is an issue with our DHCP settings.

Any ideas?

**Notes**:

- IE, Chrome, and Firefox. No proxies in place. No error messages or anything when they stop being able to load pages. Simply just "waiting for...[whatever url]" other computers are the network are still visible as is the network drive. ping for google is 16ms.
- pinging google from the command line still works when no other pages will load. existing pages seem to still work. gmail and gchat in particular will still work sometimes even while no other pages will load.

Comment: This sounds like a network configuration error.

Comment: Whats the ping count like the to DNS address? Is the network/sys admin using an internal or external dns server? are you using a proxy server? and what web browsers have you tried? Please update your question.

Comment: Any proxies in place?  when they stat being unable to load new pages, what exactly happens?  Any errors reported?  When they start failing, can you load "new" sites via their IP address?  when they are failing can you contact other machines on the LAN (by name)? Aside form refreshing the IP and restarting, what else have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
```

Flushing the DNS may help but it does sound like a DHCP setting issue if it is that widespread.

Comment: Why does it sound like DHCP if the OP can ping Google while the connection is not working properly?

Comment: Ah... good point... Asker: do they all drop at the same time or do they all drop separately? Could it be an issue with an image used to set these up? (Possibly didn't sysprep to reset Security Identifiers?)

Comment: No they definitely drop individually. We have about 50 computers in 4 areas and 1 or 2 different computers will be down at a given time and we restart them as fast as possible but they are taking half an hour to shut down. They were stable for the first few months I worked here. We run Envisionware, PCreservation and clean-slate on all the public machines.

Comment: What do you mean by 'they are taking 1/2 hour to shut down?' Also, is it the same computers repeating the problem, or is it affecting all the computers, just at different times?

Comment: it is affecting all the computers at different times. When we restart the computers it will often take half an hour or so for windows to finish shutting down. The boot times are about normal.

Comment: Wow, that is abnormal. I would look at the images... there is something going on with the local installs of Windows on those machines. Additionally, make sure your tools (when creating the images) are set up to regenerate SID's (I know there is debate as to whether these actually affect the network functionality or not, but I would do it anyways.)

Comment: How would I look at the images? I'm not sure what that means. Would something like this work? http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: It's possible that running a repair may fix it. How do you go about deploying these machines? are each one set up individually from scratch or do you guys set 1 up, make a copy of it, and deploy that copy to the other 50 machines? In that case, the copy is called an image.

Comment: Also, did you try doing a 'ipconfig /flushdns' as i mentioned above?